# Granting permission to table in database to an unknown user

Tags: php, postgresql

I created a new table in the database but whenever I try to access it with an existing PHP system I get the following error message: **permission denied for relation myTable**

When I check in the connect file in PHP they connect like this `$conn = pg_Connect("","","","","database");` which I think is not the best way to connect to a database, but I can't change this for a couple of reasons.

Ho can I grant priveliges to myTable in Postgres for an unknown user?

This is what I was thinking

```
database=> grant all on myTable to "";
```

Is this the correct way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
   ON yourtable
   TO public;
```

Or:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
   ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public
   TO public;
```

[Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html).

Be wary of giving more permissions than needed to anonymous users, though.

Comment: Note that (special group) public means (always) **all** roles (within used DB cluster).